# is there any way to use ChangeNotifier with ValueListenableBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

I have this example `ChangeNotifier`:

```
class ExmapleNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDark = false;

  toggleTheme() {
    isDark = !isDark;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

when I try to use it with a `ValueListenableBuilder`, it throws an error that it's not a `ValueListenable`, is there any way to combine them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I may go with ChangeNotifierProvider. You can also use `AnimatedBuilder` widget.

```dart
class CHTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const CHTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final exampleNotifier = ExmapleNotifier();
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: exampleNotifier,
      builder: (context, child) => Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text("is Dark ${exampleNotifier.isDark}"),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: exampleNotifier.toggleTheme,
            child: Text("toggle"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```